# How to insert image to Email of Edition Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I need insert logo_image to Email edition notification ( Jenkin ) 
How can I do it

- Insert image in HTML Email Edition of Jenkins
- When Email have been sent ( Reader recieved : an Image inside the email )

Everyone know help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage jenkin / Configure system / Extend email notification / Default context Type = **HTML ( html/text)**